# How can I hide tooltip in Chart.js on a specific data label?

Tags: javascript, typescript, canvas, chart.js

I am trying to hide a tooltip in [Chart.js](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chart.js) whenever the name of a clicked object is "Something". I have already tried this:

```
  this.doughnutChart = new Chart(this.doughnutCanvas.nativeElement, {
  type: 'doughnut',
  data: {
    datasets: [{
      label: _.map(this.dataService.AmTimeSlots, 'ProjectName'),
      data: _.map(this.dataService.AmTimeSlots, 'Duration'),
      backgroundColor: _.map(this.dataService.AmTimeSlots, 'Color'),
      hoverBackgroundColor: _.map(this.dataService.AmTimeSlots, 'HoverColor'),
      borderColor: _.map(this.dataService.AmTimeSlots, 'BorderColor'),
      borderWidth: 1.5
    },
    {
      label: _.map(this.dataService.PmTimeSlots, 'ProjectName'),
      data: _.map(this.dataService.PmTimeSlots, 'Duration'),
      backgroundColor: _.map(this.dataService.PmTimeSlots, 'Color'),
      hoverBackgroundColor: _.map(this.dataService.PmTimeSlots, 'HoverColor'),
      borderColor: _.map(this.dataService.PmTimeSlots, 'BorderColor'),
      borderWidth: 1.5
    }],
  },
  options: {
    elements: {
      arc: {
        roundedCornersFor: 0
      }
    },
    segmentShowStroke: false,
    responsive: true,
    maintainAspectRatio: true,
    legend: {
      display: false
    },
    onClick: this.chartClick.bind(this),
    cutoutPercentage: 65,
    tooltips: {
      filter: function (tooltipItem) {
        if (tooltipItem.xLabel == "Free Slot") {
          return false;
        } else {
          return true;
        }
      },
      callbacks: {
        label: function (tooltipItems, data) {
        return data.datasets[tooltipItems.datasetIndex].label[tooltipItems.index];
        },
        afterLabel: function (tooltipItems, data) {
        return Math.floor(data.datasets[tooltipItems.datasetIndex].data[tooltipItems.index] / 6) + 'h ' + data.datasets[tooltipItems.datasetIndex].data[tooltipItems.index] * 10 % 60 + 'm';
        }
      }
    }
  },
  config: {
    data: this.dataService,
    settings: this.settingsService
  }
});
```

And this code above is working fine. It’s successfully hiding the text of tooltip, but the problem is that the black label/border still remains. How can I hide it?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You can simply [filter](http://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/configuration/tooltip.html#filter-callback) tooltips:

```
options: {
    tooltips: {
       filter: function (tooltipItem, data) {
           var label = data.labels[tooltipItem.index];
           if (label == "Red") {
             return false;
           } else {
             return true;
           }
       }
    }
}
```

See this jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/beaver71/ndc2uao2/

Comment: it didn't hide the black label/background so the effect is the same as my code

Comment: have you checked again? is it ok?

Comment: i see that it works in fiddle, but somehow it doesn't work in my application, what can be the possible reason?

Comment: xLabel is empty in my case, maybe because I am using doughnut chart?

Comment: try to share your code (more complete as possible), for example in a jsfiddle

Comment: Chart.js version?

Comment: i have added more code in first post, chart.js version is 2.7.0

Comment: Yes, I think it depends on chart type: however I updated my answer

Comment: i have changed your code a little because i am using `2 datasets`, but it's working, i dont know why havent i noticed that there is an `index` field on `tooltipItem`

Comment: I noticed filter function doesnt work for me in 2.9.4. I just took over a 5 years old project and tried to hide tooltips for some values, but man, combining label and title tooltip callbacks and filter doesnt seems to work (i'm on a line chart; with A LOT of data)

Answer (score 5):

Update for Chart.js 3:

```
options: {
  plugins: {
    tooltip: {
       filter: function (tooltipItem, data) {
           return tooltipItem.label === "Red";
       }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Even if the code *looks* simple, an explanation would be in order. E.g., what is the idea/gist? What changed? Is there some story behind such (breaking) changes? Etc. Perhaps link to official statements?  From [the Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/promotion): *"...always explain why the solution you're presenting is appropriate and how it works"*. Please respond by [editing (changing) your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/68860870/edit), not here in comments (***without*** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the answer should appear as if it was written today).