# How to hide tooltip for selected datasets? - Chart.js v2.8

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I have this graph with four datasets. Two that shows count of values and two lines that represent a goal or target for each value. What I want is to group all tooltips while hovering but exclude the two tooltips for the goal lines. How does one do that?

The following code shows some mockup numbers for the data, and the tooltip shows me all the labels.

```js
var ctx = document.getElementById('myChart');
var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
  type: 'line',
  data: {
    labels: ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June"],
    datasets: [{
        label: 'Count type 1',
        data: [48, 33, 32, 35, 42, 38],
        backgroundColor: 'transparent',
        borderColor: 'rgba(255, 204, 0, 1)',
        fillColor: 'rgba(255, 204, 0, 0.1)',
        pointBorderColor: 'transparent',
        pointBackgroundColor: 'rgba(255, 204, 0, 1)',
        pointRadius: 4,
        borderWidth: 2,
        lineTension: 0.3
      },
      {
        label: 'Goal 1',
        data: [48.000, 47.040, 46.080, 45.120, 44.160, 43.200],
        backgroundColor: 'transparent',
        borderColor: 'rgba(0, 255, 0, 1)',
        fillColor: 'transparent',
        pointBorderColor: 'transparent',
        pointRadius: 0,
        borderWidth: 0.4,
        lineTension: 0
      },
      {
        label: 'Count type 2',
        data: [24, 37, 30, 22, 29, 18],
        backgroundColor: 'transparent',
        borderColor: 'rgba(255, 0, 0, 1)',
        fillColor: 'rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.1)',
        pointBorderColor: 'transparent',
        pointBackgroundColor: 'rgba(255, 0, 0, 1)',
        pointRadius: 4,
        borderWidth: 2,
        lineTension: 0.3
      },
      {
        label: 'Goal 2',
        data: [24.000, 23.520, 23.040, 22.560, 22.080, 21.600],
        backgroundColor: 'transparent',
        borderColor: 'rgba(0, 255, 0, 1)',
        pointBorderColor: 'transparent',
        pointRadius: 0,
        borderWidth: 0.4,
        lineTension: 0
      }
    ]
  },
  options: {
    tooltips: {
      enabled: true,
      mode: 'index',
      intersect: false,
    }
  }

})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.8.0/Chart.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="myChart"></canvas>
```

I have tried various methods, some that works half way (excludes only one dataset) or with too much extra code and 'blinking' or flickering tooltips while disappearing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Final version (I hope). Shortly after my answer I stumbled upon this plugin which is exactly what I really was looking for.
https://github.com/chartjs/chartjs-plugin-annotation

```js
var ctx = document.getElementById('myChart');
var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
  type: 'line',
  data: {
    labels: ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June"],
    datasets: [{
        label: 'Count type 1',
        data: [48, 33, 32, 35, 42, 38],
        backgroundColor: 'transparent',
        borderColor: 'rgba(255, 204, 0, 1)',
        fillColor: 'rgba(255, 204, 0, 0.1)',
        pointBorderColor: 'transparent',
        pointBackgroundColor: 'rgba(255, 204, 0, 1)',
        pointRadius: 4,
        borderWidth: 2,
        lineTension: 0.3
      },
      
      {
        label: 'Count type 2',
        data: [24, 37, 30, 22, 29, 18],
        backgroundColor: 'transparent',
        borderColor: 'rgba(255, 0, 0, 1)',
        fillColor: 'rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.1)',
        pointBorderColor: 'transparent',
        pointBackgroundColor: 'rgba(255, 0, 0, 1)',
        pointRadius: 4,
        borderWidth: 2,
        lineTension: 0.3
      }
    ]
  },
options: {
  responsive: true,
  tooltips: {
     enabled: true,
      mode: 'index',
      intersect: false, 
    },
    
    annotation: {
        annotations: [{   
            type: 'line',  
            mode: 'horizontal',
            drawTime: 'afterDatasetsDraw',
            id: 'a-line-1',
            scaleID: 'y-axis-0',
            value: 48,
            endValue: 43,
            borderColor: 'rgb(75, 192, 192)',
            borderWidth: 2,
            label: {
                backgroundColor: 'rgba(255,204,0, 0.4)',
                fontColor: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6 )',
                fontSize: 12,
                enabled: true,
                content: 'Goal from 48 to 43',
                yAdjust: -18,
                xAdjust: 0,
            }
        },
        {
            type: 'line',   
            mode: 'horizontal',
            drawTime: 'afterDatasetsDraw',
            id: 'a-line-2',
            scaleID: 'y-axis-0',
            value: 24,
            endValue: 21,
            borderColor: 'rgb(75, 192, 192)',
            borderWidth: 2,
            label: {
                backgroundColor: 'rgba(255,0,0,0.4)',
                fontColor: 'rgba(255, 255, 255 )',
                fontSize: 12,
                enabled: true,
                content: 'Goal from 24 to 21',
                yAdjust: 14,
                xAdjust: 0,
            }
        }]
    },
    
    scales: {
        yAxes: [{
            scaleLabel: {
                display: true,
                labelString: 'interface'
            },
            ticks: {
                beginAtZero: true
            }
        }]
    }
}

})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.8.0/Chart.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://rawgit.com/chartjs/chartjs-plugin-annotation/master/chartjs-plugin-annotation.js"></script>

<canvas id="myChart"></canvas>
```

Answer (score 1):

While working on the question I stumbled up on this solution using filter. It is based on a [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48151428/) to simular question.

```
filter: function (tooltipItems, data) {
    var label = data.datasets[tooltipItems.datasetIndex].label;
    if ((label == "Goal 1")||(label == "Goal 2")) {
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Here is the code from my original question including this filter.

```js
var ctx = document.getElementById('myChart');
var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
  type: 'line',
  data: {
    labels: ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June"],
    datasets: [{
        label: 'Count type 1',
        data: [48, 33, 32, 35, 42, 38],
        backgroundColor: 'transparent',
        borderColor: 'rgba(255, 204, 0, 1)',
        fillColor: 'rgba(255, 204, 0, 0.1)',
        pointBorderColor: 'transparent',
        pointBackgroundColor: 'rgba(255, 204, 0, 1)',
        pointRadius: 4,
        borderWidth: 2,
        lineTension: 0.3
      },
      {
        label: 'Goal 1',
        data: [48.000, 47.040, 46.080, 45.120, 44.160, 43.200],
        backgroundColor: 'transparent',
        borderColor: 'rgba(0, 255, 0, 1)',
        fillColor: 'transparent',
        pointBorderColor: 'transparent',
        pointRadius: 0,
        borderWidth: 0.4,
        lineTension: 0
      },
      {
        label: 'Count type 2',
        data: [24, 37, 30, 22, 29, 18],
        backgroundColor: 'transparent',
        borderColor: 'rgba(255, 0, 0, 1)',
        fillColor: 'rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.1)',
        pointBorderColor: 'transparent',
        pointBackgroundColor: 'rgba(255, 0, 0, 1)',
        pointRadius: 4,
        borderWidth: 2,
        lineTension: 0.3
      },
      {
        label: 'Goal 2',
        data: [24.000, 23.520, 23.040, 22.560, 22.080, 21.600],
        backgroundColor: 'transparent',
        borderColor: 'rgba(0, 255, 0, 1)',
        pointBorderColor: 'transparent',
        pointRadius: 0,
        borderWidth: 0.4,
        lineTension: 0
      }
    ]
  },
  options: {
    tooltips: {
      enabled: true,
      mode: 'index',
      intersect: false,
      filter: function(tooltipItems, data) {
        var label = data.datasets[tooltipItems.datasetIndex].label;
        if ((label == "Goal 1") || (label == "Goal 2")) {
          return false;
        } else {
          return true;
        }
      }
    }
  }

})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.8.0/Chart.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="myChart"></canvas>
```