# Chart JS - Points and Tooltips Only at Specific Data Values

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I am currently using chart.js to plot spectral data from a EMI receiver. There are over 16000 (x,y) data indexes within each dataset and therefore I have made it so only the lines show without any points.

I now have a list of a few certain (x,y) value pairs that I would like to put points/markers on and add tooltips for. Is there a way to add tooltips and/or points or markers to only certain (x,y) value pairs within each dataset?

Any help would be appreciated. I will update with any photos/code if needed as I currently do not have an attempt at a solution for this.

EDIT1:
As you can see, it is very difficult to select the maximum point of the peaks due to how many data points make up the chart. I want to select only the local maximums and display tooltips for those points.

[image]

Comment: You could look to use custom tooltips? https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/configuration/tooltip.html#external-custom-tooltips

Comment: Can you try this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48147259/how-to-hide-tooltip-in-chart-js-on-specific-data-label/48151428. I think the `filter` setting is what you are looking for.

Comment: @adelriosantiago that looks like it might work! Thanks!

Comment: @adelriosantiago The filter setting looks like it works for the tooltips, however I still haven't figured out a way to only make certain points clickable. Because there are so many datapoints, it is tough to click on specific ones and I only want to click the local maximums. I will edit my post with a photo of my current chart.

Answer (score 0):

options.elements.point has a prop called radius. Radius can take either a number or an array of numbers. A single number will determine the radius for all of the points in your chart but the array will be able to determine each element's radius. This way you are able to selectively determine each point's radius with full control.

A solution for your example might look like this:

```
const options = {
    elements: {
        radius: allPoints.map(point => {
            const maxPoint = Math.max(allPoints)
            // return radius 0 for every point that is not the max and radius 1 (or bigger if needed) for the maximum point 
            return point == maxPoint ? 1 : 0
        })
    }
}
```

Comment: How would you define `AllPoints`?