# Hide tooltip when hovering over null-values in chart.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, chart.js, react-chartjs

I am currently using a line-chart with chart.js 3.5.0 and react-chart-js 3.0.4, given two datasets.

The first dataset has data in {x,y}-format with null-values for some y.
When hovering over those null-values, the tooltip jumps to the start of the second dataset. In this case, I would like to hide the tooltip, but approaching the problem with callbacks didn't work.

Has anybody experienced the same issue?

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yQcns.png)

[codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/modest-aryabhata-wvlznm?file=/src/components/CChart.jsx)

```
const options = {
    interaction: {
        intersect: false
    },
    maintainAspectRatio: true,
    animation: false,
    plugins: {
        tooltip: {
            mode: 'nearest',
            axis: 'x',
            position: 'average',
            yAlign: "bottom"
        },
    },
    scales: {
        y: {
            type: 'linear',
            beginAtZero: true,
            min: 0,
            grace: '20%',
        }
    },
    chartArea: {
        backgroundColor: "rgb(240,240,240)"
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you tried something to hide them ?

Comment: Yes, I tried to define a filter function as a callback as mentioned in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48147259/how-can-i-hide-tooltip-in-chart-js-on-a-specific-data-label

But somehow I am not even able to access the values on this point

Comment: Include it in your question then

Answer (score 0):

You can use `mode: 'x'` in your tooltip config.
Together with setting `pointHitRadius` to 0 in both datasets makes it so you dont have duplicate values in your tooltip.

Example: https://codesandbox.io/s/hardcore-brown-1vxcjh?file=/src/components/CChart.jsx